# IIS 7.5 site can't authenticate itself

Tags: php, iis, iis-7.5

I have a couple of sites on the same server and same domain (site1.domain.com, site2.domain.com...) which talk to each other with http post request. This works fine, but I also have a dev version of all sites that is under basic authentication so you need a username/password to see the sites, and on these the http post request doesn't work.

This seems to be because the server can't authenticate itself which seems kinda weird to me, I don't have much experience with IIS thou so probably have missed something.

Anyone know how to solve this?
Don't know if it makes a difference, but the sites are using php, not asp.net

Comment: show some code? how are you making the requests? How do you try and authenticate?

Comment: It's Drupal7 sites so i'm using the [drupal_http_request()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7) function. site2.domain.com just makes a request to site1.domain.com/xxx where a script runs that do some database querys and then returns the result.

All dev sites (where it doesn't work) are using the Basic Authentication option in IIS.

Comment: So you need to send auth credentials with your request, not a drupal user, but this might help: https://drupal.org/node/715990

Comment: Maybe a bit unclear, but it's not the drupal authentication that is a problem, it's the IIS server authentication that is the problem.

To even access the sites you have to login with a user created on the server, the IIS authentication. So the problem is that when I do the request to site1.domain.com/xxx the server can't access that url since it isn't authenticated against the server.

Comment: yes i get that, so you need to send credentials in the http request. in c# .net you would do request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user,password); You would need to do something similar in all your requests, if this isnt possable with drupal_http_request methods, you can create the authorization header yourself by base64 encoding your credentials

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) Don't think here is any way to accept your comment as answer is there?

Comment: Nope, so i made an answer you can accept. Glad i could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to send your credentials with your request. I do not know much about drupal_http_request, but if it doesnt have built in methods to add credentials to the request, you can manually add an auth header by base64 encoding your credentials.